# jQUery-DataTables FixedColumn plugin doesn't work on IE and FireFox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, plugins, datatable

I am using datatables, and when i use FixedColumns plugin, it's fine in Chrome, but in FF and IE, the horizon scrollbar didn't showup, when i paginate to next page, the scrollbar shows, and when i paginate to next page again, the scrollbar missed again. Also, in FF and IE, the columns are mis-aligned when the fixed column works. I don't know what's going on.
Below is my code:

```
var oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({
    'sScrollX':'100%'
});
new FixedColumns( oTable, {
    "iLeftColumns": 2,
    "iRightColumns": 0
});
```

In your code, you comment that if 'sScrollX' is used, the columns will be mis-aligned, but when i removed this parameter, the fixed column don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally fount the cause of this issue, we use bootstrap together with datatables, and bootstrap set max-width of table to 100%, after remove this style, it's ok.